Is there a way to record and save all playing audio in a NW.js application?
I want to record and save to a file the sound a NW.js application makes.
I have a singleton AudioContext available, but I want it both recorded and playing in the speakers.
I tried to create a fake AudioContext via https://github.com/descriptinc/web-audio-js but it doesn't seem to fully implement the functionality my application needs.

Not an audio expert, so you will need to do additional research on your own.
You could look into how to handle this at a Chromium or Node.js level. Assuming you can funnel the live data into a buffer, that could be handed to Node's fs to save it to a file. You may want to store this in a temporary location first, like require('path').join(nw.App.dataPath, 'temp.wav'), then when recording is done, relocate the file to where the user wants.
That's just an idea though, without research. Good luck.

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

